# Hide or Protect .txt save data c#

Tags: c#, save, text-files, password-protection

I have a program where a User can put data in a listBox, and this listBox can be saved by button click encrypted to an .txt file.

With any program start, the program loads and decode the Save-data back to the listBox.

So if anyone opens the save.txt, nobody can read it because its encrypted, but the users are still able to manipulate the encrypted textfile, so its not possible to load it back in my listBox.

Is the a way that my Form App, saves this .txt in a password protected folder or make something like invisible .txt files, only the Program can see?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx - though it is possible to configure Windows Explorer to display hidden files. Also see this : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con

Comment: If you save that file in the users Documents folder shouldn't it by design already be protected for writing? Assuming you're not running that program on Windows 95 ....

Comment: if people are not logging in with the same windows users, just set the file permissions for read write for each user. If not , save the data to a Database or Server to prevent others to corrupt the file.

Comment: See [System.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You may make your file, Hidden, or even give it a System attribute that can be a precaution, but still, it is not very safe.

You can use SqlServer database to save your list, that handles encryption for you. (of course, if the user has admin privileges) he can still open and manipulate its data.

You may use `Properties.Settings` (AppSettings) too, but as I already said each option can have its advantages but not 100% safe, for a user with privilege.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to work out is if you are over thinking this, is not hiding it and encrypting enough, why are people going to track down your file and mess with it?

However you do have a plethora of options, though you can hide it as much as you like yet the only way to stop dirty little fingers touching your data is put behind a remote web server.

However failing that,

- You can stuff it in a database with restricted permissions
- Put it in App Settings where its less obvious to find
- and/or Create an account and impersonate that user in your application and programmatically restrict permissions to your file
- Hide it in the registry (meh)
- You could do something weird like append it to the end of a dll
- Even change the extension to your file, and sociologically impersonate another file type like an exe or dll, make it less obvious

Though really if you want to restrict it, just create a web sever, give the user a login and password, and save it there, no dirty little fingers.